# Re-throw exception or call System.exit() to end the program. What is the best practice?

Tags: java, exception

There is a try-catch block and inside the try block an Exception might be thrown. When this exception is thrown it doesn't make sense to continue in execution. I want to log occurrence of this exception into the log too. I do so and then I want to exit the program.

Should I call `System.exit(1)` or just call `throw e`? Does it even matter? What is "the best practice" here?

```java
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Wow this is severe! We are done here!", e);
    //do I call "throw e" or "System.exit(1)" here?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no best practices.

There are only **your** requirements.

For some programs, the correct answer could be to *exit* the JVM immediately.

But yes, most of the time, you prefer to either

- rethrow your exception
- throw another exception
- don't throw anything

Those are the three "common" options for handling exceptions. Which one to pick: again depends on your requirements and the behavior you **want** your program to have.

Final words: `System.exit()` is something that should be used in very small "tools like" applications. Something goes wrong, you give a clear error message, you stop. In any larger application, there should be exactly one layer/component that decides to tear down the JVM and everything with it. Because larger applications aren't meant to suddenly die on their users. To the contrary.

Comment: My feeling is that there should be a very limited number `System.exit() ` calls and definitely not hidden many layers deep into your code.   @GhostCat - Keep well.

Answer (score 1):

- if you just want to rethrow why catch ? just for logging it
- also depends on how and where this method is being called, is this a library?
- nothing else happens after this? in the code which is calling this
- if there is no way to handle the issue, why not throw an Error?
- System.exit(1) terminates the JVM whereas Exception will allow the program to recover
- if this is a library and you want to indicate the client this is a major issue and cannot be handled throw an Error

To summarise

1. throw Error if there is no way for client to recover
2. throw Exception if there is a way to recover
3. last thing to use would be System.exit(1) and when there is no client for the code.